# cmake glob include while preserving directory structure

Tags: c++, installation, cmake, directory-structure, glob

I'm new to `cmake` and I'm trying to install `.hpp` files while preserving directory structure.

So far I have

```
FILE(GLOB files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyLib/*.hpp"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyLib/detail/*.hpp"

install (FILES ${files}  DESTINATION include)
```

All the files get found but the directory hierarchy is flattened.

FWIW The `bjam` command I'm trying to emulate is

```
install headers 
    : ../include/EnsembleLearning.hpp  
      [ glob ../include/MyLib/*.hpp ]  
      [ glob ../include/MyLib/detail/*.hpp ]  
    : <install-source-root>../include ;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the DIRECTORY variant of the CMake [install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3ainstall) command. This command will preserve the structure of the copied directory:

```
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION include
          FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp")
```

If the directory to be copied contains subdirectories that should not be installed, you'll have to explicitly exclude those with a PATTERN EXCLUDE option:

```
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION include
          FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp"
          PATTERN "include/MyOtherLib" EXCLUDE)
```

Comment: This does not work for me with current cmake-2.8.5. Either no files are installed or if I omit the FILES_MATCHING line everything gets installed. Any ideas?

Comment: This is the line I am using: `INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
        PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)`  I can also omit the line `PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)` and it still changes nothing.

Comment: Looks good to me. Try the option `REGEX "^.*\\.h$"` instead of `PATTERN "*.h"`

Comment: OK, that's weird. It works on Linux (Ubuntu) but does not work on OS X. So this seems to be a platform issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As I found out right now this problem is OS X specific and is already reported in their bug tracker: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=10366